# Javascript to 'find and replace' from mySQL output

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am looking for Javascript expertise to be able to find specific words after mySQL outputs my text. I have numerous fields in a column in my phpmyadmin database with sentences such as: `Bobby ran down the hill. He saw nothing. Bobby went home.`

I would like to create a javascript code that finds the periods `.` and be able to replace them with html code `<br>` because I cannot add a line break in the mySQL fields even though I've tried concatenation. Help on this issue would be appreciated!

Here is my script:

```
 $("#tips").append("<li class='treatment'>" + treat.Tips + "</li>");
 $("#tips-text").text(treat.Tips);
 treat.Tips = txt.replace(/\./g, "<br />");
 $('#tips').listview('refresh');`
```

Comment: why you can not insert <br> in your mysql fields? a personal reason or grammatically?

Comment: I have tried \n, <br>, as well as them in quotes. However, I believe it is because I am using a SQLite manager for web apps and instead of doing line breaks it instead shows the actual text ie `<br>` on the front-end.

Comment: The code up there looks like you are replacing `treat.Tips` after you added that string the DOM? Just updating `treat.Tips` is not going to update the DOM. You have to call `$("#tips").append("<li class='treatment'>" + treat.Tips + "</li>");` after you run your regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) can do that with the help of regular expressions:
the method normally would replace one instance of the found text, but if you user regular expressions, it can replace all instances

I used the regex `/\./g`: this means find any `period`and the `g` modified means that the search is global for all the text.

```
var txt = "Bobby ran down the hill. He saw nothing. Bobby went home.";

txt = txt.replace(/\./g, "<br />");
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/sj33gg07/

> Thank you for your answer. I am pulling treat.Tips from phpmyadmin
>   that contains my data. Do you have any suggestions on how to further
>   display replace? I revised my code par your suggestion but it broke my
>   script. Please see my revised question for the code, thanks! – 
>   chronotrigga 4 mins ago

You should do the append after you replace not before

```
 treat.Tips = treat.Tips.replace(/\./g, "<br />");
 $("#tips").append("<li class='treatment'>" + treat.Tips + "</li>");
 $("#tips-text").text(treat.Tips);
 $('#tips').listview('refresh');`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am pulling `treat.Tips` from phpmyadmin that contains my data. Do you have any suggestions on how to further display replace? I revised my code par your suggestion but it broke my script. Please see my revised question for the code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) and look for the dots and replace it for `</ br>`

Here is an example:

```
var text = "Bobby ran down the hill. He saw nothing. Bobby went home.";
text = text.replace(/\./g,"<br />");
```